# Run mysql queries from django fabfile

Tags: django, fabric

How can I run SQL queries with my fab file as below

```
def allow_webservers_for_db():

    for ip in env.web_servers:
        run('echo "GRANT ALL ON %s.* TO \'%s\'@\'%s\' IDENTIFIED BY \'%s\'; | mysql --user=%s --password=%s"' % (env.db_schema, env.db_web_user, ip, env.db_password, env.db_user, env.db_password), pty=True)
        run('echo "UPDATE db SET host=\'%s\' where db=\'%s\'; | mysql --user=%s --password=%s --database=mysql"' % (ip, env.db_schema, env.db_web_user, env.db_password), pty=True)
        run('echo "UPDATE user SET host=\'%s\' where user=\'%s\';| mysql --user=%s --password=%s  --database=mysql"' % (ip, env.db_web_user, env.db_user, env.db_password), pty=True)
```

Code runs with no error but not doing what it has to do. If I copy and paste the code produced by `echo` to mysql terminal `mysql>` query runs properly.

What I'm missing here? Is there anyway to run mysql queries better? I don't want to load it from text file either.

Answer (score 3):

You are just echoing the whole string. 
But you want to echo the first part into the pipe to mysql. 
Remove the last `"` and place it between `;` and `|`.

Example for first line:

`run('echo "GRANT ALL ON %s.* TO \'%s\'@\'%s\' IDENTIFIED BY \'%s\';" | mysql --user=%s --password=%s' ....`